# Returning specific value from imported JSON

Tags: python, json, list

This is my first time retrieving JSON information from a webpage.
My goal is to show the current gold price, which I'd like to retrieve from a free source.

The current code is working:

```
    import urllib.request
    import json

request = urllib.request.urlopen("https://forex-data-feed.swissquote.com/public-quotes/bboquotes/instrument/XAU/USD")
data = json.load(request)
print(data[0])
```

I expected this imported data to be a dict type, but it is a list somehow?

The print:

```
{'topo': {'platform': 'MT5', 'server': 'Live1'}, 'spreadProfilePrices': [{'spreadProfile': 'Standard', 'bidSpread': 14, 'askSpread': 14.1, 'bid': 1921.59, 'ask': 1921.9}, {'spreadProfile': 'Premium', 'bidSpread': 12.7, 'askSpread': 12.7, 'bid': 1921.59, 'ask': 1921.9}, {'spreadProfile': 'Prime', 'bidSpread': 11.3, 'askSpread': 11.3, 'bid': 1921.59, 'ask': 1921.9}], 'ts': 1598379583052}
```

Now I'm trying to receive the value stored in spreadProfile Standard -> 'ask'.

This is probably a rookie question but I'm not getting **why** I'm unsuccesful.
Could anyone provide me help with this and especially on **how** did you come up with the solution?

Comment: The url you specify has `[{topo:...}]`. The `[...]` makes it a list. Nothing you can do if that's the way your data comes to you.

Comment: The output is a list because that is what is provided in the original source. If you want to get your required stuff, try this: data[0]['spreadProfilePrices'][0]['ask'] <- this assumes `'spreadProfile': 'Standard'` is the first element of the array

Comment: Once you have the dict (`data[0]`), what's the problem accessing its `spreadProfilePrices` list and finding which of these elements have `spreadProfile == 'Standard'` and returning its `ask`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The print is not a list, but a dict.
The webpage is returning a list of dicts and by doing `data[0]`, you're selecting the first dict in the list. (Are you sure you want to select the first one?)

In order to get ask, you would first you need to find the Standard profile.
I do that here by looping through all the profiles and testing, if the one that is looped through is Standad.
If the one we're looping through is in fact Standard, then just select 'ask' and break out of the loop.

```
for profile in data[0]['spreadProfilePrices']:
     if profile['spreadProfile'] == 'Standard':
          print(profile['spreadProfile']['ask'])
          break
```

You should read more on what how lists and dictionaries work in Python :)
Here are some resources I'd personally recommend:

Python lists: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp

Python dicts: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

Comment: You are completley right, I never tried printing out data[0] type... I've learned something today thank you for your time and effort!